# Change browser URL using Jquery in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, url, routes

pardon if question looks silly. In one of my project where I'm using Codeigniter framework, I have URL of home page as given below:

```
http://localhost/project/controller/function
```

Using config file **routes.php**, I have made it look like the one given below:

```
http://localhost/project/function
```

But at some places I have used `redirect()` function, because of which the URL again becomes like this

```
http://localhost/project/controller/function
```

I have tried using jquery `parent.location.hash`, but it just appends the text after the URL. For eg: if I click on Login, the URL will be  `http://localhost/project/function/login`

The same this also happens in [git](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap), where on clicking any URL, a small part of page changes along with URL. I want to do the same thing. Does anyone have any clue how to do that?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a terrible idea. You want the user to see a URL that they aren't actually at. That will create massive problems when users begin sending links to your site. This is a hacky solution that doesn't actually fix anything. Instead, redesign your website using a different structure and routing schema to satisfy your desired urls. I imagine there is an elegant solution if you read up on codeigniter's URI documentation.

To answer your git example - the reason that the page content changes and the URL changes is that it is sending you to a new page. Look at the Regular Expressions section under the second link.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I have used codeigniter routing to remove the controller name from URL. But, in TankAuth, they have used `redirect()` in `login()`, because of which when user comes to home page from any other page, the URL becomes `http://localhost/project/controller/function`. Isn't there any way, by which I can achieve the same result, without modifying much of my code?

Comment: How are you linking to the home page? Are you giving an absolute path or relative or constructed or what?

Comment: When someone clicks on logo, he is directly redirected to `auth/login`.